# Set array dimension at runtime

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, struct

I have a struct, which, depending on user inputs at runtime, will either require a 1D array or a 3D array. It will never need both. Right now, I have it set up like in the sample code below, with separate variables that can point to either a 1D array, or a 3D array. I would like to have just one variable in the struct that can point to either a 1D array or a 3D array, where the dimension is set at runtime. I have intermediate knowledge of C, and am a beginner with C++. I'd be willing to accept an answer based on C++ concepts but *only* if there is no slowdown (or negligible slowdown) compared to using C when iterating over the values. If it's a 3D array, then the for loops that access and change the array's values are the biggest bottleneck in my code. Once the array is set up, I won't need to change the dimension or size of the array.

Is there a way to do this, or should I just settle for always having an extraneous variable in my struct?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct {
  int dim;
  int *one_d_arr;
  int ***three_d_arr;
} Struct;

int main() {
  int count = 0;
  int *arr1 = (int*) malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
  arr1[0] = 0;
  arr1[1] = 1;
  int ***arr3 = (int***) malloc(2 * sizeof(int**));
  for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    arr3[i] = (int**) malloc(2 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
      arr3[i][j] = (int*) malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
      for (int k=0; k<2; k++) {
        arr3[i][j][k] = count++;
      }   
    }   
  }
  Struct s;
  s.one_d_arr = NULL;
  s.three_d_arr = NULL;
  cout << "Enter number of dimensions: ";
  cin >> s.dim;
  if (s.dim==1) {
    s.one_d_arr = arr1;
    cout << s.one_d_arr[0] << ", " << s.one_d_arr[1] << endl;
  }
  else if (s.dim==3) {
    s.three_d_arr = arr3;
    cout << s.three_d_arr[0][0][0] << ", " << s.three_d_arr[0][0][1] << endl;
    cout << s.three_d_arr[0][1][0] << ", " << s.three_d_arr[0][1][1] << endl;
    cout << s.three_d_arr[1][0][0] << ", " << s.three_d_arr[1][0][1] << endl;
    cout << s.three_d_arr[1][1][0] << ", " << s.three_d_arr[1][1][1] << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "Must enter 1 or 3" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to use `new` (instead of `malloc`) in C++.

Comment: So tag ended as `c++` - looks more `c` style to me.

Comment: A pointer is not an array! You don't have a 3D array in your question. Being a 3-star programmer in C or C++ is not a compliment!

Comment: Is this some school assignment where you are forced to use code like that? If not - you should check what `c++` containers can do for you, e.g. vectors

Comment: In C++ the type of a variable must be fixed at compile time. And the dimension of an array is part of its type. So literally, the answer is no. However, practically speaking there's any number of ways to deal with this. (1) Always make it a 1D array (or better a vector maybe!), and use a boolean flag to indicate how you are supposed to handle it / traverse it. (2) Have two different structs, and select between them when you get the data.

Comment: Firstly, code using your type would decide at compile time how to use it, but the syntax for different dimensions differs. So, what happens if you use a 3D array with the 1D syntax? Since it's the same type, the compiler will not be able to detect this. I think that your very approach is flawed, maybe taking a step back and describing your problem would help. Further, please read a C++ tutorial. Your code makes a bunch of mistakes that proper learning should be able to avoid.

Comment: In C++ one should use no arrays at all. What is your real problem?

Comment: You could use a vector, which is essentially a dynamic array. However if you're using pointers, you need to make sure that you get another pointer if you resize the vector, or add anything to it, as the previous pointer will become invalidated.

Comment: Instead of flipping arrays back and forth between 1D and 3D, create a class that has a 1D vector, and member functions that access the elements using either the 1D or 3D "formula" to get to an entry in the vector.

Comment: `set array size at runtime == std::vector`

Comment: @SouravGhosh What does UB stand for?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Why did you remove the C tag from my question? I code in C but include a few C++ things here and there for convenience, and people seem to be confused because of the lack of a C tag.

Comment: @4386427 Yes, I included a C tag originally.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which part of the code makes you shudder? I'd love to learn from everyone, and if you could make constructive comments explaining which parts could be improved I would appreciate it.

Comment: I didn't remove the tags, I only removed the tags from the title, where they shouldn't be (as per site rules). That said, if you compile as C++, it is C++, not C, there is no mix like C/C++. There are even things that are frowned upon in C (casting the returnvalue of `malloc()`) while they are necessary in C++ (`static_cast` required).

Comment: @BenLindsay As you're asking for it: ***Almost every single line***! I think it started at `int ***three_d_arr;`. [Don't do such insane stuff.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: @Olaf I know that a pointer isn't an array, but doesn't the `three_d_arr` pointer point to the first element of a 3D array after the memory is allocated?

Comment: @BenLindsay: NO! A 3D array is something like `int i[1][2][3];`, a pointer to a 3D array `int (*i)[1][2][3];`, mind the parenthesis! And the first element of a 3D array is a 2D array (try figuring out the syntax!), not "a pointer to pointer"

Comment: @4386427 No this isn't a school assignment. I can change things however I want. I'm just a newbie with C++, but it sounds like I need to learn more about C++ containers.

Comment: @BenLindsay To me, the biggest problem with the code you posted is the lack of organization. You've got one big main method which does everything, making it impossible to reuse that code anywhere else. Perhaps you can try coming up with a design, then post on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get some constructive feedback? Later on, you could replace those int***s with [Boost data structures](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @bullsy This is just a crappy sample code I wrote up to demonstrate that I have a struct with two different pointers, that I allocate data that either acts like a 1D or 3D array. The full code I'm using is much much larger. It looks a little better than this, but it does still have the problem of using triple \*'s. If I replace int\*\*\* or double\*\*\* variables with Boost data structures, will the speed of for loops referencing and changing the data in the structures be affected? (I won't change the size of the structures once they're set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use two different types here, instead of a single struct. Using an abstract base class, you can make both subclasses conform to a single interface, but they would have different underlying behavior. A very basic example:

```
class ArrayBase {
  int dim;

  public:
    // This function is pure virtual, which means it's impossible to      
    // instantiate an instance of ArrayBase. Any class that inherits from
    // ArrayBase must implement printArray().
    virtual void printArray() = 0;
}

class Array1D : public ArrayBase {
  int* array;

  void printArray() {
    // some code to print this one-dimensional array
  }
}

class Array3D : public ArrayBase {
  int*** array;

  void printArray() {
    // some code to print this three-dimensional array
  }
}
```

Later, when you need to use the array, you can dynamically allocate the type you need, like this:

```
ArrayBase* inputArray;

// if the user wants a 1D array
inputArray = new Array1D();

// if the user wants a 3D array
inputArray = new Array3D();

// this will call the appropriate function to print the array
inputArray->printArray();
```

If you really want to have a single type, using boost::any is one way to condense your two array pointers into one. I would not recommend this approach, but it would work.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it points me in a good direction to restructure my code. I'll spend some time learning about classes and other C++ containers before implementing something like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the juicy things about the C/C++ pointers is the existence of ***void*** pointers. A ***void*** pointer can point to anything you want, from ***int*** to ***int*** ***.
So you can simply use the following code:

```
#define CAST1(arr) ((int *)arr)
#define CAST3(arr) ((int ***)arr)
#define CAST(arr,i) CAST##i(arr)

typedef struct {
    int dim;
    void *arr;
} Struct;

int main()
{
    Struct s;
    cin >> s.dim;
    int count = 0;

if (s.dim == 1){
    s.arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    CAST(s.arr, 1)[0] = 0;
    CAST(s.arr, 1)[1] = 1;
}
else if (s.dim == 3){
    s.arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int ***));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        CAST(s.arr, 3)[i] = (int **) malloc(2 * sizeof(int **));
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            CAST(s.arr, 3)[i][j] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
                CAST(s.arr, 3)[i][j][k] = count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (s.dim == 1) {
    cout << CAST(s.arr, 1)[0] << ", " << CAST(s.arr, 1)[1] << endl;
}
else if (s.dim == 3) {
    cout << CAST(s.arr, 3)[0][0][0] << ", " << CAST(s.arr, 3)[0][0][1] << endl;
    cout << CAST(s.arr, 3)[0][1][0] << ", " << CAST(s.arr, 3)[0][1][1] << endl;
    cout << CAST(s.arr, 3)[1][0][0] << ", " << CAST(s.arr, 3)[1][0][1] << endl;
    cout << CAST(s.arr, 3)[1][1][0] << ", " << CAST(s.arr, 3)[1][1][1] << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Must enter 1 or 3" << endl;
}

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good to know. However, based on the comments, it looks like the best answer will be a more major overhaul of my coding concepts. I'll wait for an answer that shows me how to clean up my code, but if none comes up, I'll select this one.